# Windows 7 Network Connections empty

Tags: windows, networking, connections

Whenever I try to look at my network connections, the window opens up empty. The only thing shown is the Organize button. I went into Device Manager and deleted my network devices, but now installation fails when I try to reload them.

Comment: If you fix this yourself, please post it as an answer, not as an edit to your question. It's perfectly acceptable and encouraged to do this. If you don't think question will linger on in the "unanswered" list and keep jumping to the front page from time to time. Plus, you get the rep from both if someone finds it useful :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

solution:

I fixed it by deleting the following registry key and rebooting:

HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\Config

Note: I found the suggestion on [this site](http://goo.gl/aAVcQ).

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem when connecting to a FQDN UNC share name.  However, when I just used the IP address or just the hostname, I was able to see the contents without any problem.

- I tried the solution linked to above and deleted the config registry
  entry and rebooted, but it did not resolve it.
- Also, all 4 of my
  entries in
  HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\Connections\ClassManagers
  were on separate lines.

I added a new DWORD entry here:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters

Name: DirectoryCacheLifetime
Value Data is 0. (Hexadecimal is selected)
Click OK
Then Reboot

My folder contents re-appeared after rebooting.  So the DirectoryCacheLifetim fixed the problem for me.  I am not sure why the empty network shares suddenly though.  This was always a Windows 7 Pro machine and I have not every had any network problems with it, and it's a pretty clean install.  Users do not have admin access to install anything.

The Fix source was found here:
https://dslmac2.wordpress.com/2013/03/29/empty-folders-in-windows-7-on-network-but-others-can-see-files/